# <error> ReactElementExtended.js:30 - Error when integrating "React-Slick" ReactJS Module

Tags: javascript, slider, reactjs, carousel, slick.js

When I integrate [react-slick](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick) ReactJS module into my project I get the following error in Chrome's console. What does this error message mean? Did I integrate the module incorrectly?

```
<error>ReactElement.createElement @ ReactElementExtended.js:30ReactElementValidator.createElement @ ReactElementValidator.js:396React.createClass.render @ Slider.js:26ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:775ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:801ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:235ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:70ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ ReactReconciler.js:38ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ ReactCompositeComponent.js:245ReactPerf.measure.wrapper @ ReactPerf.js:7070ReactCompositeComponentMixin
```

This is what what my code looks like:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react');
var Slider = require('react-slick');

var Slider = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        type: React.PropTypes.string        
    },
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            type: 'track'
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        var settings = {
          dots: true,
          infinite: true,
          speed: 500,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        };

        return (
            <Slider {...settings} >
                <div><h3>1</h3></div>
                <div><h3>2</h3></div>
                <div><h3>3</h3></div>
                <div><h3>4</h3></div>
                <div><h3>5</h3></div>
                <div><h3>6</h3></div>
            </Slider>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Slider;
```

This is what my webpack.config.js looks like:

```
'use strict';

var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'sourcemap',
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, 
        loaders: [
          'jsx-loader?harmony'
        ]
      },
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loaders: ['jsx?harmony'] },
      { 
        test: /\.less$/, 
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader' 
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      { 
        test: /\.(png|jpg|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
      } // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
    ]
  }
};
```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-howto-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bundle-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.12.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "less": "^2.5.0",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "radium": "^0.11.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.4.1",
    "react-style": "^0.5.5",
    "react-style-webpack-plugin": "0.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.12.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "webpack": "^1.8.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "invariant": "^2.0.0",
    "object-assign": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^0.13.2",
    "react-router": "^0.13.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a problem with your react component class names.

In your posted code you define react-slick as class `Slider` after that you override `Slider` with your own `Slider` component class. So the component tries createing itself.

Just rename your `Slider` component.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */    
var React = require('react');
var Slider = require('react-slick');

var SimpleSlider = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        type: React.PropTypes.string        
    },
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            type: 'track'
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        var settings = {
          dots: true,
          infinite: true,
          speed: 500,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        };

        return (
            <Slider {...settings} >
                <div><h3>1</h3></div>
                <div><h3>2</h3></div>
                <div><h3>3</h3></div>
                <div><h3>4</h3></div>
                <div><h3>5</h3></div>
                <div><h3>6</h3></div>
            </Slider>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = SimpleSlider;
```